# Error adding a node to Docker UCP

Tags: docker-ucp

I'm trying to add a node to a fresh UCP install using the copy-paste from the web UI and getting this error on the node:

```
FATA[0000] The join command is no longer used. To join a node to the swarm, go to the UCP web UI,
      or run the 'docker swarm join' command in the node you want to join.
```

I'm unable to find any reference to this error or any documentation about 'join' being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` command has been deprecated.

After you have installed UCP, go to `Resources -> Nodes -> Create a Node`

There you will get a `docker swarm join` with a Swarm token and manager url. Paste this in the worker/manager node you want to join to the main UCP master.

Otherwise, using the CLI type `docker swarm init --advertise-addr <HostName of the manager>` command. It will generate a swarm token. Use that in the worker/manager node you want to join to the main UCP master